# popcon failed is the mailto address busted?

Tags: debian, email, popcon

in my mail today ( I checked it today, the messages started 5 days ago)
I got messages from popcon the package popularity contest which says:

```
...
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  survey@popcon.debian.org
    Mailing to remote domains not supported
...
```

does anyone else get that? as in, is the email address not working?
is the popcon package borked?
I am in Debian Jessie, on my personal laptop where I installed Jessie before it was a stable release. In case any of that might be a factor.

Comment: In case it's not clear, the whole message is coming from your local mail server (running on your laptop). The message "mailing to remote domains not supported" means that the server refuses to deliver mail to a remote domain (in this case, `popcon.debian.org`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty much self-explanatory.  You need to configure your mailserver to be able to send mail outside your local domain.

Comment: hmm, it used to work. perhaps something else has busted. ok then.

Answer (score 1):

popularity-contest use HTTP push for submitting. SMTP is used as a fallback
when HTTP fails.

popularity-contest is able to detect whether a MTA is installed or not, but not whether the MTA is able to send email to the popcon.debian.org server.

http://popcon.debian.org/FAQ

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=741104